# How to associate imported users from LDAP to an organization?

Tags: ldap, liferay

I dived into portal.properties but could find anything to achieve this.
Are there some existing params needed to configure the same while importing from LDAP or is doing it via plugin(programmatically) the only last option for this.Still looking for my options and have thoughts from others before I proceed for my last option.

Comment: From what I could understand so far,there is no direct way to associate users to an organization at import time(without an ext plugin) but post import we can assign user/user group to a certain role(day LDAP user group) and associate the role to an organization.Is the understanding partially correct?